# Accessing flash map from Jade template in Scalatra

Tags: pug, scalatra, scalate

I'm creating application using Scalatra and I'm using Scalate/Jade for templating. I try to add flash support to my application. I mixed `FlashMapSupport` into into my Servlet and I'm able to access `flash` helper. Anyway, if I'm trying to get it from layout I receive following error:

```
[error] /home/ytaras/projects/scala/scalatra-shopping-cart/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/scalate/templates/layouts/default_jade.scala:27: not found: value flash
[error]                         flash.get("alert").foreach
[error]                         ^
[error] one error found
```

The best I could do to avoid that was to use downcast to render context:

```
  - context.asInstanceOf[org.scalatra.scalate.ScalatraRenderContext].flash.get("alert").foreach
    - alert =>
    .alert
      .button(type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert") &times;
      = alert
```

Anyway, that's definitely not a prettiest solution. Is there something I can do to fix it or it's an issue in Scalate/Jade code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just done a very simple Scalatra app using Jade, it seems to work as per the docs.

Edit: I had been working with an app generated in an earlier version of Scalatra.

In Scalatra 2.2.0, we added precompiled Scalate templates in the g8 skeleton, to give extra speed in production by default. There's an error in `project/build.scala` in there which causes flash context to get lost.

Add this to your `project/build.scala`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ff40cdde1a1105970f50#file-build-scala-L37-L39

We'll fix the g8 template momentarily. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Could you clarify what type of info might help? Thanks

Comment: Hi Yura, can you show the action and views, as I've done? Also, if you need real-time help, there's a very active community in the #scalatra irc channel on Freenode.

Comment: Sure - here's git repository I'm talking about - https://github.com/ytaras/scalate_shopping_cart

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking with some other people now to see whether there's a bug here, I've reproduced your example in a standalone application.